# Script-wide redirection to internal logger function

Tags: bash, function, redirect, logging, exec

I wrote a big Bash program composed of several shell scripts organized throughout a deep directory tree. The program is complex and it is fundamental to have a proficient debugging and logging infrastructure.
Within one of the sub-scripts, I wrote a logger function capable to receive log messages and route these toward the appropriate MySQL tables.

The logger function has a plain simple input interface which accepts only one argument, the log message, and can be imagined as a special version of the `echo` builtin which prints directly into the database, with the routing being determined internally.
In code this translates to:

```
# generic code, somewhere in the program
if success; then
     log_f "Previous function returned success"
else log_f "Previous function returned failure"
fi
```

This approach has the defect of being only able to log those messages which are explicitly meant to pass thru `log_f`; that is, any error messages generated by external binaries or by Bash itself won't be saved in the database.

A simple solution could walk along the line of `exec >log 2>&1`, which would register everything coming out from stdin and stderr into `log`. However, I need to store log messages in database and not on file.

Also, `exec` seems to be incompatible with pipe redirections, like `exec | log_f`. (log_f modified to support stdin).
The only solution I can think of, which is ugly, is to set a redirection of the whole script(s) during their invocation, like:

```
# I am a starter of sub-scripts
a_script_in_the_tree.sh 2>&1 | log_f
```

However, it would be preferable to let each script manage its own logging method internally, using its own set of functions available within its scope.

Comment: Are you aware of `{ cmd1; ...; } | log_f`?  It handles I/O redirection for the code within the scope of the braces, similar to but not as radical as, `exec` -- and usable with pipelines (with caveats about where variables are set and read).

Comment: This would require to pipe almost every and each command of the program toward the logger individually, if I want to collect all the output from the script. A bit of insane IMHO.

Comment: I just realized that the whole script could be put inside `{}`, except for the definition of `log_f`. However, I have global variables, alas.

Comment: You could use a launcher to start your script. A public, clean interface that calls your scripts and pipes their IO to your function.

Answer (score 1):

> A simple solution could walk along the line of `exec >log 2>&1`

A named pipe could take the place of the log file although this would require a fifo-to-sql process to consume the output and send it to the database. This would give you 'self-reliance' of the per-script redirect while adding a burden that each script would need to fire up an idempotent consumer. Does this trade one ugliness for another?

Here is a simple pair of scripts which demonstrate the idea, the script in need of logging services:

```
$ cat nplog.sh
#!/bin/bash

logfifo=/tmp/log.fifo
if [ ! -p $logfifo ]; then
    # should maybe spawn npreader here
    echo logging system is not running: $logfifo does not exist 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

exec > $logfifo 2>&1 

while true; do
    date
    cat /does.not.exist
    sleep 1
done
```

and the cheezy reader

```
$ cat npreader.sh
#!/bin/bash

# oversimplified for illustration. should remove the fifo upon exit so
# that clients can't attach when reader is down

logfifo=/tmp/log.fifo
mkfifo $logfifo
cat $logfifo
```

Answer (score 0):

Just came out of my head:

```
exec > >(log_f) 2>&1
```